# Rally Custom report integration in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, rally

I have developed a custom report in Rally - and this needs to be integrated in the Sharepoint portal - how do I proceed doing this ( similar to the standard reports working in the API Kit and  through Javascript on sharepoint) ?

Am using Sharepoint 2010 and 1.0 version of Rally

Raghu

Answer (score 1):

As Nick says, there's nothing in the api that will help you here, but you might be able to get what you want "manually".  The "shape" of the custom report endpoint url is:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/analytics/reports/<id>/run?PROJECT=<project oid>
```

where `<id>` is the id of the report (which you can get by hovering over it in the Reports tab index) and `<project id>` is the id of the project from which to gather data.

ex:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/analytics/reports/1001883/run?PROJECT=20383843
```

(don't bother trying that as is, those are dummy ids).  You'll still need to use the appropriate LoginKey.

Answer (score 0):

Custom reports created on Rally's Reports>Reports page do not have an equivalent to [StandardReport](https://help.rallydev.com/standard-reports) component in legacy [AppSDK1](https://help.rallydev.com/app-sdk) or [StandardReport](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.report.StandardReport-cfg-autoEl) in AppSDK2. In the absence of a similar wrapper for custom reports it is not possible to display them outside Rally the way Standard Reports can be displayed.

You may however write your own javascript custom app (using [AppSDK1](https://help.rallydev.com/app-sdk) or [AppSDK2](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/)), build a deployment html file out of it and paste the html code to Sharepoint web part. This app will have to access Rally data you want to visualize in a grid, for example.

Also, both Standard Reports and custom reports on Reports>Reports page are generated by legacy analytic service. It does not support the new [ApiKey](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/guide/embedding_apps). In the case of StandardReport you need to use old [LoginKey](https://github.com/RallyTools/Login-Component-Example).